# How to set the length prop for the angular material paginator

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

This is what my `mat-paginator` looks like:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" [length]="100"></mat-paginator>
```

Basically I'm trying to implement a typical pagination idea: the server does not return all the data, it returns a chunk of it and then when a new page is opened it goes for another fraction of data. In order to do that, I need to let the paginator know how many items are there in the database, that's to say, I need to provide it with the `length` prop.

I tried setting it in a variety of ways, directly like in the line above or inside the method where I make a get request. Like this:

```
this.paginator.length = 100;
```

Indeed the length should come from the server but for the time being for debug purposes I simply hardcode it.

```
    this.dataSourceService.findAll().subscribe(
      records => {
        this.paginator.length = 100;

        this.dataSource.data = records.map(
          record => new Record().deserialize(record)
        )
      }
    )
```

Still the length value I get on the client is equal to the number of items contained in the array I get in the server response.

What am I doing wrong and why the length value is not set to 100.

***EDIT***:

Alright, here is some more relevant code.

Inside the component I do the following:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Record>();
pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 20];
```

inside the `OnInit()` I also have the following line: `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;`

Comment: Post the relevant code. Currently, the only thing we can see about your code is that you have `[length]="100"`. We have no idea of what paginator is, how it's used, etc. Stackblitz is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using it like this

```
<mat-paginator
          [pageSize]="pageSize"
          [pageIndex]="pageNumber-1"
          [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50, 100]"
          [length]="itemCount"
          (page)="changePaging($event)"
>
```

lets say that the return of your observable is an object { list: [], count: xx } count is the total items (without pagination)

```
this.list$ = this.dataSourceService
      .findAll()
      .pipe(tap(r => (this.itemCount = r.count)));
```

of course you can subscribe after that for more actions...

check the docs also https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api

Answer (score 6):

For other people walking into the same problem as me:

If you have your `dataSource` connected to your `paginator`, it will overwrite any values you set.

Remove this:

```js
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```